GCP logs explorer showing ERROR log in INFO severity
I have following python code running in GKE
...
import logging


log = logging.getLogger('APP1')
logging.basicConfig(format="%(message)s", stream=sys.stdout)
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

...

if __name__ == '__main__':
...
    log.info("Task ongoing")
    except Exception as e:
        log.error("got exception", exc_info=1)
        log.exception(f"got exception {e}")


In GCP Logs Explorer, the error, exception, info all are shown in INFO severity. How can I make the error or exception to be in ERROR severity?
